# Video shortcode, option are not rendered

Tags: shortcode

I'm using some custom shortcodes without problem. I'm trying to create a custom video shortocode but wordpress always removes `autoplay loop muted playsinline` on rendering. `Poster` works perfectly. Do you have idea why ?

```
function video_custom() {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'option' => '',
        'poster' => '',  
        'src' => '',
        'type' => '',     
        ), $atts ) );
    
    return '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><video class="wp-video" '.$option.' poster="'.$poster.'"><source src="'.$src.'" type="video/'.$type.'" /></video></div>';
    }
    add_shortcode('video_custom', 'video_custom');
```

Comment: Check the raw/server-generated HTML source (press `Ctrl` + `u` on Chrome, desktop/non-mobile) and see if the `<video>` tag actually has those attributes - if yes, then it's JS that's removing them. And if so, then check for any WordPress core video/media scripts which are loaded on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assign for `$atts`. So suprised that the poster can work correctly.

```php
function video_custom($atts)
{
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'option' => '',
    'poster' => '',
    'src' => '',
    'type' => '',
  ), $atts));
  return '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><video class="wp-video" ' . $option . ' poster="' . $poster . '"><source src="' . $src . '" type="video/' . $type . '" /></video></div>';
}

add_shortcode('video_custom', 'video_custom');
```